# If a polynomial with certain consecutive odd integers (in some order) as coefficients has an integer root, then that root is $-1$

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we put all odd positive integers in a triangle,like so:
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
1 \\\
3 & 5 \\\
7 & 9 & 11 \\\
13 & 15 & 17 & 19 \\\
..&..&..&..&..
\end{array}$$

> The question: The polynomial $P$ has degree $m$ (where $m\geq2$), and its coefficients are (in random order) all the numbers from the row $m+1$. Prove that, if $t$ is an integer root of said polynomial, then $t=-1$.

Example of polynomial when $m = 2$ : $9X^2+7X+11$

These are some details that i have arrived at:

- Because all the coefficients are positive, the root must be negative.
- Because all the coefficients are odd, then, if the root is an integer, it must be odd.
- However we choose two different numbers from the same row, they don't divide eachother.

Comment: No, your polynomial when $m =2$ doesn't have root $t = -1$

Comment: @NN2 Yes, because the polynomial doesn't have any integer roots. That statement is true only if it has integer roots, and if it has, then it must be $-1$

Comment: Does any of these polynomials have an integer root?

Comment: @lhf If we choose $m=3$, then the polynomial $17X^3+19X^2+15X+13$ has the root $t=-1$

Comment: Will the highest degree term dominate the sum of the others when $|x|\ge3$? Seems likely given that we have control of the (alternating) signs.

Comment: If $m$ is $1$ mod $4$ then the claim is true, the reduction mod $2$ has a single root at $1$ of multiplicity $1$, so we only have the obvious $-1$ integral root over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Interesting fact: if $f_m(x) = 1+ x+\ldots+ x^m$, then $P_m(x) = A_m f_m(x) + 2 f'(x) $, where $A_m$ is some odd integer.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I see. Then the polynomials with even $m $ also drop out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that an odd integer $-\ell<-1$ is a root of such a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m c_i x^i$. Then, collecting the terms sharing the same sign to same side, we get
$$
\sum_{0\le i\le m, i\equiv1\pmod2}c_i\ell^i=\sum_{0\le i\le m, i\equiv0\pmod2}c_i\ell^i.
$$
Let $c_{-}$ be the smallest coefficient on the side matching the parity of $m$, and let $c_{+}$ be the largest coefficient on the opposite side. Then on the side of $i=m$ we have
something that is $$\ge c_{-}(\ell^m+\ell^{m-2}+\cdots)=c_{-}\ell^m/(1-\ell^{-2}).$$
On the opposite side we have a quantity that is
$$\le c_{+}(\ell^{m-1}+\ell^{m-3}+\cdots)=c_{+}\ell^{m-1}/(1-\ell^{-2}).$$
As $\ell\ge3$, elementary estimates give that
$$\ell c_{-}>c_{+},$$
so this is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, because $lc_{-} \ge 3 ((m+1)^2 -m) > ((m+2)^2 -(m+3)) \ge c_{+}$ then the last inequality holds true.

Comment: Is that first inequality obvious?